# Scipy minimize with multiple constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints

I am struggling to optimize on a small block of data. I have cash in different currencies held in different banks. The cash can be negative as well as positive. The interest rates vary across banks. I want to minimize (maximize) the interest in **aggregate** by shuffling the cash around between banks. Interest is calced as simply the balance multiplied by the rate.

2 constraints exist:

1. The sum per currency at the end should be the same as the start.
2. The sum per account shouldn't fall below some minimum level per this:

A: 8
B: 20
C: 15

Initial start data:

```
BANK   CCY  BALANCE RATE
A      USD  7       0.15%
B      USD  60      0.12%
C      USD  -40     0.05%
A      EUR  5      -0.40%
B      EUR  -30    -0.50%
C      EUR  80     -0.60%
```

So I wrote a minimize function for when it is just one currency so it can respect the start sum of a currency equaling the end sum. but with one currency, that is fairly easy. How do i expand it so that multiple currencies can be dealt with WHILE respecting the minimum sum required at each bank?

Comment: I would suggest to first develop a mathematical model of the problem. My guess is that this would show this problem is an LP (Linear Programming) problem. SciPy has `linprog` for this.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thanks for the response. Would you mind suggesting further why you think this is a LP problem? I am off to read up on it regardless.

Comment: I have not verified this rigorously (that would require building a mathematical model), but it looks to me, at first sight, that the objective function and the constraints are all linear, and that the decision variables are continuous.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thanks for the guidance. Made some good progress down the LP avenue with PuLP. I figured the above data needed to be arranged as an array which could then have constraints applied to columns/rows. Now on to the next part of having the interest rate switch depending on if balance is negative or positive.

Comment: Great! Yes, PuLP should be helpful for this,